# how to record tsung-recorder sessions in linux server proxying/tunnelling through windows browser

Tags: stress-testing, tunneling, tsung, tsung-recorder

i have tsung setup in my remote linux server.(54.54.90.90) no browser here. 
i have my windows machine (122.122.130.130) where i browse my web app through firefox. i have changed firefox settings to use SOCKS proxy on port 8090 (http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/) to route all traffic from my windows laptop to linux box to the internet rather than from windows laptop to internet.

now i started tsung-recorder which runs by default in 8090, hoping whatever requests i make in my windows laptop will be recorded here. but no session is recorded.

I want to record a tsung-recorder session in my linux machine as i browse in my windows laptop. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just configure an HTTP proxy on Firefox and point it to the remote server where your tsung-recorder ran using port 8090.

Comment: I shouldn't have used SOCKS proxy rather just http proxy at 8090 as pointed out. thanks Rodolphe.